# Pandas, Get count of a single value in a Column of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas, I would like to get count of a specific value in a column.I know using df.somecolumn.ravel() will give me all the unique values and their count.But how to get count of some specific value.

```
In[5]:df
Out[5]:
        col 
         1
         1
         1
         1
         2
         2
         2
         1
```

Desired :

```
  To get count of 1.

  In[6]:df.somecalulation(1)
  Out[6]: 5

  To get count of 2.

  In[6]:df.somecalulation(2)
  Out[6]: 3
```

Comment: Are you optimizing this for multiple queries, or for a small (or single) query?

Comment: My favorite is `df.col.eq(1).sum()`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df['col'].value_counts().reset_index()
df.columns = ['col', 'count']
print df
   col  count
0    1      5
1    2      3
```

EDIT:

```
print (df['col'] == 1).sum()
5
```

Or:

```
def somecalulation(x):
    return (df['col'] == x).sum()

print somecalulation(1)
5
print somecalulation(2)
3
```

Or:

```
ser = df['col'].value_counts()

def somecalulation(s, x):
    return s[x]

print somecalulation(ser, 1)
5
print somecalulation(ser, 2)
3
```

EDIT2:

If you need something really fast, use [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

#for testing len(a) = 6000
a = pd.concat([a]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

print np.in1d(a,1).sum()
4000
print (a == 1).sum()
4000
print np.sum(a==1)
4000
```

**Timings**:

`len(a)=6`:

```
In [131]: %timeit np.in1d(a,1).sum()
The slowest run took 9.17 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.9 µs per loop

In [132]: %timeit np.sum(a == 1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 196 µs per loop

In [133]: %timeit (a == 1).sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop
```

`len(a)=6000`:

```
In [135]: %timeit np.in1d(a,1).sum()
The slowest run took 7.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.5 µs per loop

In [136]: %timeit np.sum(a == 1)
The slowest run took 5.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 273 µs per loop

In [137]: %timeit (a == 1).sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 271 µs per loop
```

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake in question.i have edited it.Now see it.

Comment: If you need count single item, `np.in1d` is faster as accepting solution. Please see edit2 and timings. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you take the `value_counts` return, you can query it for multiple values:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])
counts = a.value_counts()
>>> counts[1], counts[2]
(4, 2)
```

However, to count only a single item, it would be faster to use

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(a == 1)
```

Comment: Some might like to do `a.eq(1).sum()`

Answer (score 2):

Get the total count:

```
column = df['specific_column']

column.count()
```

Get the specific value total count:

```
column.loc[specific_column > 0].count()
```

You do not need to add quotes ('') to indicate `specific_column`.

Comment: You definitely need quotes or else you will get an error `NameError: name 'specific_column' is not defined`

Comment: `column` in the second code block should be `df`